# Inconsistent styling and formatting in the notices for closed questions

Tags: bug, design, closed-questions, information-display, post-notices

While using my Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google Chrome app version 12.41.19.23.arm64 in "full site" view at [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions) (the only site where I have the necessary privileges)...

[image]

[image]

Both of these questions ([here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/76892/35069) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/76875/35069)) were closed as "off topic" for the same reason and at roughly the same time. However, despite these similarities their notices (i.e. the "blue headers") are inconsistent:

- The former has an option to edit, unlike the latter - is this a bug or deliberate?
- Bonus bug - the former's box around the option to edit has a size / shape fault forcing a new line which splits *"questi-on"*.

Comment: Does anyone else find the font sizing here unsightly? Why is "closed" and the rest of that line so much smaller?